# Given $f(x,y)=y+xh(x,y)$, prove that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y) = h(x,y)\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y)$

Tags: derivatives

I have $h(x,y)=g(f(x,y))$

The relationship between $f$ and $g$ are expressed with $h$ $$f(x,y)=y+xh(x,y)$$

Prove that $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y) = h(x,y)\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y)$$

---

I tried from two sides

$$h(x,y)\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y) \\\ = h(x,y) \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(y+xh) \\\ = h(x,y) (1+x)\frac{\partial h}{\partial y} \\\ = h+xh \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(y+xh)$$

$$f(x,y)\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \\\ =\frac{\partial }{\partial x}(y+xh)  \\\ = \frac{\partial }{\partial x} xh \\\ = 1 + \frac{\partial h}{\partial x}$$

I can't delete $h$ on right side.
Where did I get wrong?

Comment: Are you sure there isn't a typo somewhere with your givens? With the work that I have, I get that the statement can only be true if $h = \frac{h_x}{h_y}$. It's also possible that there's someway that last statement is implied already, I just can't see it.

Comment: @NinadMunshi Yes I've checked a few times and it was correct, how did you lead the conclusion by the way?

Comment: $$f_x = h + xh_x$$ and $$f_y = 1 +xh_y$$ Based on your username is this from an undergrad multivariable calculus class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the relationship to rewrite the expression solely in terms of $f$

$$f(x,y) = y + xg(f(x,y))$$

Then take partial derivatives to get the system of equations

$$\begin{cases}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = g(f) + x g'(f)\cdot\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \\ \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = 1 + x g'(f)\cdot\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \\ \end{cases} \implies \begin{cases}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\left(1-xg'(f)\right) = g(f) = h \\ \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\left(1-xg'(f)\right) = 1  \\ \end{cases}$$

which means that

$$\frac{\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}}{\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}} = h \implies \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y) = h(x,y) \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y)$$

This may sound like a powerful statement, but in reality there is probably only a very small family of functions that would satisfy those two relationships ($g = $ const is one such trivial relationship)